# How to do the pushout with universal property?

Tags: commutative-diagrams

More precisely, the following the graph:

[image]

Moreover, if I want to factorise `$\alpha':B\to Y$` as `$\alpha': B\xrightarrow{p}Z\xrightarrow{h}Y$`, how can I do it?

Comment: Do you want `\alpha'=gf`?

Comment: @Sigur yes that's what I want

Comment: But `f,g` can not be composed.

Comment: @Sigur Sorry, I feel confused. Why?

Comment: Why are you confused or why can not be composed? If 1st, I have no idea; if 2nd, because both have the same domain. How to compose?

Comment: @Sigur we can not represent \alpha' as a composition?

Comment: `\alpha'=\theta \alpha`.

Comment: @Sigur f is from B to Z, g is from Z to Y. Why do you think f,g have the same domain?

Comment: See the image you posted.

Comment: @Sigur I mean I want to add a Z between B and Y  and two maps f,g in that image, with f:B\to Z, g: Z\to Y.

Comment: You can not use `f,g` to those maps since you already used these letters. Choose another name.

Comment: Where should be `Z`? Below `B` or `D`?

Comment: @Sigur Sorry about that, I was careless about the notation. I have edited, I mean add maps p,h not f,g

Comment: @Sigur Z should be below D, actually, I want to use ph to replace \alpha'

Comment: I think now with all those codes you can try to adapt as you wish. I put `Z` below `B`. Sorry.

Comment: Welcome. I think code is very intuitive. right, left, down, up, and so on... like in tabular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[all]{xy}

\begin{document}
\[
\xymatrix@R=1.2cm@C=1.2cm{
 A \ar[r]^{g}      \ar[d]_{f}         & C \ar[d]_{\beta} \ar[rdd]^{\beta'}   \\
 B \ar[r]^{\alpha} \ar[rrd]_{\alpha'} & D \ar@{-->}[rd]|{\theta}             \\
                                      &                                   & Y 
}
\]

%% bended arrow
\[
\xymatrix@R=1.2cm@C=1.2cm{
 A \ar[r]^{g}      \ar[d]_{f}         & C \ar[d]_{\beta} \ar@/^1pc/[rdd]^{\beta'}   \\
 B \ar[r]^{\alpha} \ar@/_1pc/[rrd]_{\alpha'} & D \ar@{-->}[rd]|{\theta}             \\
                                      &                                   & Y 
}
\]

%% not too symmetric, but....
\[
\xymatrix@R=1.2cm@C=1.2cm{
 A \ar[r]^{g}      \ar[d]_{f}         & C \ar[d]_{\beta} \ar@/^1pc/[rdd]^{\beta'}   \\
 B \ar[r]^{\alpha} \ar@/_1pc/[rrd]^{\alpha'}\ar[d]_{p} & D \ar@{-->}[rd]|{\theta}             \\
 Z \ar@/_1pc/[rr]^{h}                                      &                                   & Y 
}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image] [image][image]

Answer (score 3):

I recommend `tikz-cd`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
A \arrow[d,"f"'] \arrow[r,"g"] &
C \arrow[d,"\beta"'] \arrow[ddr,bend left,"\beta'"] \\
B \arrow[r,"\alpha"] \arrow[drr,bend right,"\alpha'"'] &
D \arrow[dr,dashed,"\theta"] \\
&& Y
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

The notation `"f"'` means that the label should be set on the right side of the arrow instead of the default left side.

[image]

Omitting `bend left` and `bend right` you'd get

[image]

but the dashed arrow should be input as

```
\arrow[dr,dashed,"\theta" near start]
```

in order to avoid clash.

A version with more arrows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
A \arrow[d,"f"'] \arrow[r,"g"] &
C \arrow[d,"\beta"'] \arrow[dddr,bend left,"\beta'"] \\
B \arrow[r,"\alpha"] \arrow[ddrr,bend right,"\alpha'"'] \arrow[dr,"p"'] &
D \arrow[ddr,dashed,"\theta"] \\
& Z \arrow[dr,"h"'] \\
&& Y
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, if I want to add a Z between B and Y and two maps p,h in that image, with p:B\to Z, h: Z\to Y to replace \alpha': B\to Y, what can I do?

Answer (score 2):

A `psmatrix` solution:

```
\documentclass[border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node, auto-pst-pdf} %% to compile with pdflates --enable-write18 MiKTeX) or pdflatex --shell-escape (TeX Live, MacTeX)

\begin{document}

$ \begin{psmatrix}[rowsep = 1.2cm]
%%% Matrix nodes
  [name = A] A & [name = C] C\\
 [name = B] B & [name = D] D \\
& & [name = Y] Y
%%% Connections
\everypsbox{\scriptstyle}
\psset{linewidth = 0.6pt, arrows = ->, arrowinset = 0.15, shortput = nab, nodesep = 3pt, labelsep = 1pt}
\ncline{A}{B}_{f}\ncline{A}{C}^{g}
\ncline{B}{D}^{α}\ncline{C}{D}_{β}
\ncline{B}{Y}_{\alpha'}\ncline{C}{Y}^{\beta'}
\ncline[linestyle = dashed]{D}{Y}^[npos = 0.35]{θ}
\end{psmatrix} $

\end{document}
```

[image]

*Edit*:
 A code for the factorisation of α':

```
\documentclass[border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node, auto-pst-pdf} %% to compile with pdflates --enable-write18 MiKTeX) or pdflatex --shell-escape (TeX Live, MacTeX)

\begin{document}

$ \begin{psmatrix}[rowsep = 1.2cm]
%%% Matrix nodes
  [name = A] A & [name = C] C\\
 [name = B] B & [name = D] D \\
& [name = Z]\makebox[2em][l]{$ Z $}\qquad & [name = Y] Y
%%% Connections
\everypsbox{\scriptstyle}
\psset{linewidth = 0.6pt, arrows = ->, arrowinset = 0.15, shortput = nab, nodesep = 3pt, labelsep = 1pt}
\ncline{A}{B}_{f}\ncline{A}{C}^{g}
\ncline{B}{D}^{α}\ncline{C}{D}_{β}
\ncline{B}{Y}_{\alpha'}\ncline{C}{Y}^{\beta'}
\psset{linestyle = dashed}
\ncline{D}{Y}^[npos = 0.35]{θ}
\ncline[offsetB = -1ex, -1ex]{B}{Z}_{p} \ncline[nodesepA = -1em]{Z}{Y}_{h}
\end{psmatrix} $

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice `Z` positioning.